# PHP if validation

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following validation:

```
if (count(json_decode($PostData['images'], true))) {
    $post_images = array_combine(range(1, count(json_decode($PostData['images']))), array_values(json_decode($PostData['images'])));
    $post_images = json_encode($post_images);
} else {
    $post_images = '{}';
    $jSON['trigger'] = AjaxErro("<b class='icon-checkmark'>Tem de inserir pelo menos uma imagem.", E_USER_WARNING);
    echo json_encode($jSON);
    die();
}
```

It validates a drag and drop image made in a HTML div.
The problem is:
If i drag an image it stores the image.
But then the drag and drop stays empty and if i drag another image without refreshing the page, because $PostData['images'] is empty it throws a error that
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable.

I tried to make the proper if validation so that it stores image in database using the if clause at second drag of image but without success...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this validation.

```
if(empty($PostData['images']){
    $PostData['images'] = '{}';
}
```

Comment: No. It gives error: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable